# node.js send object from server to client console for debugging

Tags: node.js, console.log

How can I pass an object from server to client make it looking like this in the console?

[image]

I tried to use `util.inspect(myObject, {showHidden: false, depth: null})`,
but it returns a string and I cannot fold/unfold it in the console:

[image]

I tried to convert it to an object using `var obj = JSON.parse(str);`, but it gives me an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0

or `var obj=eval("("+str+")");`, but it gives me an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [`devtool`](https://github.com/Jam3/devtool) or [`node monkey`](https://github.com/jwarkentin/node-monkey) to connect node.js to your console, then you can simply use:

```
console.log(myObject);
```

Or for a more detailed view:

```
console.dir(myObject);
```

Node Inspector seems to have (had?) some issues with console ouput.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to log to stderr instead of stdout you can use:

console.error('%o',myObject)